# In Suicide Squad why don't they give Harley Anything

Tags: dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

In *Suicide Squad* Harley Quinn gets like no chair or bathroom or anything to entertain her with. Are the guards scared that she would break the things and turn it into a weapon to kill someone with? I'm just wondering because some of the other people get bathrooms but not her.

Comment: because she is the craziest one.

Comment: Actually, none of them (squad members) has bathrooms or anything. Killer Croc only has some sort of water tank, others just sit in their empty cells. On the contrary, Harley was given some ropes, which is really weird for a prison.

Answer (score 4):

> are the guards scared that she would break the things and turn it into a weapon to kill someone with

Yes.